# PNG images look blurry when scaled

Tags: image, resize, png, scale

I'm a visual/UI designer working on a project/product which has been designed by another designer. This designer provided the front-end dev with good quality PNG icons, but when the front-end dev sets the images scale to 0.7, they look blurry.

I've noticed that if we set the image's scale to 0.5, they don't look blurry at all:

0.7: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQNYG.png

0.5: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBShu.png

Anyone knows why does that happen?

I personally always work with 0.5 scales because I was taught so. Is there any logical reason for this?

Sorry if the answer is obvious. I am really curious about that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What program/tools are you using to scale them?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The front-end dev is scaling them using HTML/CSS. I got some answers on this question (please see them below) and they were very helpful.

Comment: Good question, but I don't think this is the correct site for it. I suggest this question be migrated to http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Milla, you posted several "thank you" comments below, but apparently didn't upvote helpful answers. The latter is preferred on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has to do with interpolation, when you resize an image there is no way of knowing what is supposed to be in-between the two pixels that are essentially being merged. What the computer tries to do is guess what the new pixel is supposed to look like by looking at the pixels around it and combining the values.

So for example in the image above (in the question) it will go 'what is in between white and orange?' a less  bright orange. OK lets make the merged pixel look like that. When you get to a corner there might be more orange so the new pixel will look more orangey, you get the point.

Now when you scale by 0.5 the computer looks at the pixels and merges all the pixels together at a constant rate. What I mean by that is if you look at an image and try to divide it in half you will always merge 4 pixels together however if you scale by 0.7 your merging an irregular amount of pixels resulting in different concentrations of pixels as the image is scaled which results in a blurry image.

If you don't understand this I understand, I kinda went off on a tangent.... if you need more clarification comment bellow :)

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you halve an image's size (in both dimensions), you effectively are combining exactly 4 pixels into one. However when you do a slightly off scale (such as 0.7) you have one and a fraction of a pixel going into one pixel (in each dimension). This means the data from one pixel is being used in up to 4 pixels, instead of one, causing a blurry effect.

Sorry, making an example image would be quite difficult for me, but I hope you get the concept.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening largely depends upon the software that you are using to shrink the image. There is a major different between reducing by 0.5 and 0.7.

If you shrink by 0.5, you are combining 4 pixels into one.

If you shrink by 0.7 you are doing fractional sampling. 10 pixels in each direction get reduced to 7. 
In 0.5 sampling, you read two pixels across, read two pixels down.

In 0.7 sampling you read 1.42857142857143 pixels in each direction. In order to do that you have to weight pixel values. That is going to create blurriness in a drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `.img-crisp` class to the image:

```
.img-crisp {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* Opera */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

> The image-rendering CSS property sets an image scaling algorithm. The
> property applies to an element itself, to any images set in its other
> properties, and to its descendants.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).